# Assigning value to dataframe in R - for loop speed

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
n <- 1e6

no_clm <- rpois(n,30)

hold <- data.frame("x" = double(n))
c = 1
for (i in no_clm){

  ctl <- sum(rgamma(i,30000)-2000)
  hold[c,1] <- ctl
  #hold <- rbind(hold,df)
  c = c +1


}
```

Unfortunately the speed of this code is quite slow. I've narrowed down the speed to hold[c,1] <- ctl. If I remove this then the code runs near instantly.

How can I make this efficient? I need to store the results to some sort of dataframe or list in a fast fashion. In reality the actual code is more complex than this but the slowing point is the assigning.

Note that the above is just an example, in reality I have multiple calculations on the rgamma samples and each of these calculations are then stored in a large dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hold=data.frame(sapply(no_clm,function(x){
  return(sum(rgamma(x,30000)-2000))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the rgamma repeated over as the actual calculation does more complex calculations than just summing and subtracting on each gamma observation.

Comment: This does repeat the `rgamma`, `sapply` is more or less the same as a `for` loop with some convenience.

Comment: @user33484 What zacdav said. If you think that this does not answer your question, then you should add details. "More complex" does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just use one call to `rgamma`, as you are iterating over the number of observations parameter.

So if you do one call and the split the vector to the lengths required (`no_clm`) you can then just iterate over that list and sum

```
n <- 1e6

no_clm <- rpois(n, 30)

hold <- data.frame("x" = double(n))

# total observations to use for rgamma
total_clm <- sum(no_clm)

# get values
gammas <- rgamma(total_clm, 30000) - 2000

# split into list of lengths dictated by no_clm
hold$x <- sapply(split(gammas, cumsum(sequence(no_clm) == 1)), sum)
```

This took `5.919892` seconds

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the rgamma repeated over as the actual calculation does more complex calculations than just summing and subtracting on each gamma observation.

Comment: Then use `Rcpp`. Every other option is going to be extraordinarily slow in comparison. You can potentially provide more details, and I can see what is possible with R as is.

Answer (score 0):

Move into `sapply()` loop instead of a `for` loop and then realise `2000 * no_clm` can be moved outside the loop (to minimise number of function calls).

```
n <- 1e6
no_clm <- rpois(n, 30)
hold <- data.frame(x = sapply(no_clm, function(i) sum(rgamma(i, 30000))) - 2000 * no_clm)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the rgamma repeated over as the actual calculation does more complex calculations than just summing and subtracting on each gamma observation.

Comment: @user33484 This gives the same result as your current code... just faster

Answer (score 0):

You may observe a speed pickup using data.table:

```
dt = data.table(no_clm)
dt[, hold := sapply(no_clm, function(x) sum(rgamma(x, 30000)-2000))]
```